# Handling namespaces in the XML when using XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have the following XML with name, say, "screen.xml":

```
    <tc:transform xmlns:tc="http://www.w2.prg/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<tc:blockTemplate blockTitle="Court/Agency">
<link flush="true" href="./customimages/customBlockStylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <!-- BEGIN Court Information Content -->
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <!-- Control Row -->
    <tr>
    <td class="altFieldColor" height="0" width="20%"/>
    <td class="altFieldColor" height="0" width="10"/>
    <td class="altFieldColor" height="0" width="25%"/>
    <td class="altFieldColor" height="0" width="2"/>
    <td class="altFieldColor" height="0" width="10"/>
    <td class="altFieldColor" height="0" width="20%"/>
    <td class="altFieldColor" height="0" width="10"/>
    <td class="altFieldColor" height="0" width="100%"/>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="8">
     <img border="0" height="2" src="./customimages/spacer.gif" width="1"/>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="altFieldColor" height="40">
     <tc:label category="DISP" name="CoreDocketNumber"/>:</td>
    <td class="altFieldColor" width="10">
     <img border="0" height="1" src="./customimages/spacer.gif" width="10"/>
    </td>
    <td class="altFieldColor" nowrap="true">
     **<tc:field category="DISP" name="CoreDocketNumber"/>**
    </td>
    <td width="2">
     <img border="0" height="1" src="./customimages/spacer.gif" width="2"/>
    </td>
    <td class="altFieldColor" width="10">
     <img border="0" height="1" src="./customimages/spacer.gif" width="10"/>
    </td>
    <td class="altFieldColor" height="40">
     <tc:label category="DISP" name="CoreCourt"/>:</td>
    <td class="altFieldColor" width="10">
     <img border="0" height="1" src="./customimages/spacer.gif" width="10"/>
    </td>
    <td class="altFieldColor" nowrap="true">
     **<tc:field category="DISP" name="CoreCourt"/>**
    </td>
    </tr>   
        </table>
    <!-- END Court Information Content -->
</tc:blockTemplate>
</tc:transform>
```

I am trying to write an XSL that will mostly ignore the html tags and only look at the tags with name "tc:field" and give me the following:

```
<H1>screen.xml</H1>
<ul>
<li>DISP.CoreDocketNumber</li>
<li>DISP.CoreCourt</li>
</ul>
```

The DISP is the value of the category attribute of the tc:field tag and CoreDocketNumber is the value of the name attribute.

Here's my attempt at the XSL

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:tc="http://www/w2.prg/1999/XSL/Tansform" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
      <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <ul>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="tc:field"/>
            </ul>
      </xsl:template>
      
      <xsl:template match="tc:field">
      <li><xsl:value-of select="@category"/>.<xsl:value-of select="@name"/></li>
      </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I only get the following output when I apply the xsl to the xml:

```
<ul xmlns:tc="http://www/w2.prg/1999/XSL/Tansform" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"></ul>
```

I am not sure I am handling the tc namespace correctly. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:tc="http://www.w2.prg/1999/XSL/Transform"
exclude-result-prefixes="tc">

<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <body>
            <H1>screen.xml</H1>
            <ul>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="//tc:field"/>
            </ul>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tc:field">
    <li>
        <xsl:value-of select="@category"/>
        <xsl:text>.</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
    </li>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks, @michael.hor257k, this gave me the following result:
<html>
<body>
<H1>screen.xml</H1>
<ul></ul>
</body>
</html>

Looks like the tc:field template is still not matching.

Comment: My result is different - see: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gVTWaA6

Comment: Very strange! Just for kicks, I removed the "tc:" from the match and the select, using just "//field" and "field" and the solution worked for me. I will accept the answer. Thank you very much!

Comment: You are either using a different input or working with a non-conformant processor.